# Changing firefox default download directory daily

Tags: firefox

Okey, this may sound a little weird.

I download some files every day, and there is some importance over when the files were downloaded. So, I make the directory with a date like this yyyy-mm-dd and download it in it.

But the problem is that some days I forget to change the directory (I tend to forget a lot of things before my morning tea :-|, and then I have to manually fiure out which belong where. So I thought, is it possible to make firefox switch default directories upon starting.

Making them isn't a problem - a script does that, but the second part is.

Any ideas ?

Comment: what OS are you on?

Comment: XP (and I don't need 15 chars to say that)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use an automated file organizer for this purpose. If you are using Windows, you can check out [Belvedere](http://github.com/adampash/belvedere), if on Mac, then [Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php). If on Linux, try cron jobs with a good script.

Set up the rules as such for Belvedere or Hazel to monitor a single download folder, then anytime a file drops in, it is moved to the day's folder.

Your objective is to make the second problem of forgetting to change download directories **non-existent** even. In short, you should ***not*** be changing download directories, letting automation take care of sorting out the files for you.

Comment: Exactly, I do not want to change dirs myself. I wish it to be changed daily depending on the current date. Thanks; looking it up.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a script that creates the download directory for you, it should not be a problem to let the script edit your Firefox preferences as well (of course, you'd have to do that before starting Firefox).

Simply find your Firefox profile directory which should contain a file named 'prefs.js'. This line:

```
user_pref("browser.download.dir", "/foo");
```

Would set the download dir to '`foo`'. All you script needs to do is change that line each day.